# Trane air handler twe036c140a0 create “c” wire

Tags: thermostat, wifi

Trane Air Handler twe036c140a0 Create "C" Wire
Can someone please tell me the best way to Create a "C" Wire for a Honeywell WiFi thermostat (model rth9585wf).

Comment: Can you post a picture of your wiring diagram?

Comment: Yes, can you post the wiring diagram for your air handler? Photos of the wiring at the air handler would also help....

Answer (score 0):

Based on this diagram of the control page 4 https://ww2-secure.justanswer.com/uploads/Wvfan79/2012-07-13_122319_twe036-sf-1d.pdf the "c" source is the blue wire leaving the transformer, which becomes terminal 6 at the low voltage terminal block.

If that diagram doesn't reflect your model or current control board then you would need to identify the two 24v leads from the transformer, one should attach to a fuse, the other should be the C source.